# jQuery/JS: fancybox load from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, fancybox

Right now when you make a fancybox you initialize a link and give some settings:

```
    $("a#a_sendMail").fancybox({
'titleShow'     : false,
'width':    400,
'height':   120,
'autoDimensions': false,
'overlayOpacity': 0.6
    });
```

and then you do the link with id a_sendMail, and then href="#sendMail" and then you make the div for it:

```
<div style="display: none">
<div id="newMail">
This is inside the fancybox :)
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to instead of making a div in the same file that holds the content, I would like to call newMail.php, and the output of this should be shown as a box. So when you click the link(in order to open the box), it makes a ajax request and return/response with the content that are going to show inside it.

How can I do this the most smartest and simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the href option to fancybox, like this:

```
$("a#a_sendMail").fancybox({
    titleShow     : false,
    width:    400,
    height:   120,
    autoDimensions: false,
    overlayOpacity: 0.6,
    href: 'newMail.php' // <----- this is the option 
});
```

You can view all the options right here: http://fancybox.net/api